# -eq: unary operator expected in expr length evaluation

Tags: shell, unix

Does somebody know why next expression is executed correctly in LINUX but not in UNIX?

```
SOME_DATE=201804132359    
if [ `expr length $SOME_DATE` -eq 12 ]; then
```

In those it doesn’t work we get this error:

```
[: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Comment: On what machines does it work, or not? What OS, shells, and versions are they using? What is `$SOME_DATE` and its content? What does `expr length $SOME_DATE` return? I suspect this is a dupe of one of many candidates, but there's not enough info to say...

Comment: I ampliate with the info I know

Comment: "LINUX" and "UNIX" are kernels, not actual OSes or shells... So, again: Which distributions? And what shells did you test this in? What do they return and print if you just run `expr length $SOME_DATE` at the prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because linux is porting **GNU expr** while unix is porting **POSIX expr**, and they have different synopsis.

`expr length $SOME_DATE` won't work on unix, it will casue an error, that's why you code will break.

You could change your code on unix.

```
SOME_DATE=201804132359    
if [ `expr $SOME_DATE : ".*"` -eq 12 ]; then
```

But if you just want the result, may be `[ "${#SOME_DATE}" -eq 12 ]` is a better solution.